# Configuring Ghidra to use the Keil 8051 ABI for analysis

Tags: ghidra, 8051

I am trying to reverse engineer a raw binary image from an nrf24le1 SoC that (I think) has been compiled with the Keil toolchain.  Specifically, I see that C functions in this image usually expect their arguments in r7/r5/r3 as described [here](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_ap_parampassreg.htm) and that the return value lives in r7.  The behavior I'm seeing is:

- Ghidra thinks that every function in this image takes 0 parameters, even if it's obvious that the function is immediately looking at r7 for its first argument
- Ghidra thinks the return value lives in ACC

I have to manually override this for every function.  I would like for Ghidra to automatically figure out when a function has arguments based on the Keil ABI.

By contrast, when I run Ghidra on a raw arm32 binary, it notices when a function looks for arguments in r0/r1/r2/... and it adjusts the function declaration accordingly.  So Ghidra behaves correctly for arm32, but incorrectly for 8051.

Is there a way to fix this (or is there a better tool I should be using instead of Ghidra)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [mx51](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/Ghidra/Processors/8051/data/languages/mx51.cspec) variant of the 8051 processor when loading the binary.

The file in the link uses the calling convention found in your link.